# Passing parameters throw url

Tags: drupal-7, arguments, drupal-views, drupal-panels

**Hello everyone.**

Here is my problem. I have a photo gallery content type in which i store several photos.
One of my fields is a **list field**(*named 'period'*) with 3 options (*2000-2004, 2004-2008, 2008-2012*), refers to the period the photos was taken.

Now i want to make a **main menu link**(*ex. path: /photos/2004-2008*) which leads to a page
with a view. That view is gonna take the '2004-2008' variable from the url and use it as a filter creteria. This way the view results would be the photos with 'period' field value = 2008 -2012.

Can plz someone help me? I am very confused..

**First problem,** What is the correct path for the link in main menu?

**Second,** What is the correct path for my panel page (i use panels module) which contain my view.

**Third,** how to set properly my view to do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your approach Drupal has **'Contextual filters'**. So you have to pass the url parameter and need to specify that which argument you want to catch. So if it's argument 0, 1 or 2 **( %1, %2 etc )** then that data will be collected and processed.

You can also assign your custom php code for the custom functionality. Please check with the screen shot. It's really pretty easy!
[image]

Let me know, this helps you!

**Keep Drupalizing :)**